# connecting with database and showing result on localhost

Tags: python

i changed the code as follows

```
    from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'OMTSL_QBO'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Welcome to Python Flask App!"

@app.route("/Authenticate")
def Authenticate():
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) from REPORT_SUITE")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        print ("Database version : %s " % data)    
        return data
    else:
        return "Logged in successfully"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

but i still do not see the print message on the browser window. i want to see the count message on my browser when i run it on local host

Comment: Can you please correct the indentation in `count`?

Comment: I had to add and extra tab space for "return "test"" as the code was giving an error

Comment: Is it over-indented only here or in your code as well? And please use four spaces and not tabs to indent in Python. That's the standard: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: No in my code also it is with an extra indentation

Comment: So you should replace all tabs with four spaces and fix the indentation. `return "test"` should be on the same level as all statements in `count`.

Comment: ok i replaced the tab space in my code with 4 spaces and it worked correctly without an extra indentation for the return count() statement. But please tell me why my code does not display the print message on localhost when it does so on the terminal

Comment: Did you look at my answer?

Comment: So it prints the information in the browser now? Seems like you changed the code quite a bit. If the previous problem is solved you can accept my answer.

Comment: the issue is i just want to  view the print statement on the screen, which i am not able to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **return** the actual query result you should use a `return` statement on `data` in `count`:

```
def count():
    # ... same
    print ("Database version : %s " % data)
    # return the database result from the 'count' function
    return data
```

**Edit:** If you want the exact same data make sure to return the same data:

```
def count():
    # ... create data variable
    mydata = "Database version : %s " % data
    # print data in console
    print mydata
    # return the datato caller (and then to user...)
    return mydata
```